# Show data in a Datagrid -> XAML (Simply) - C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm new in the forum,
   I have a little issue with display in datagrid.
I have try every solution that I found on the net. Please help me.

My view : [XAML view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g499e.png)

My Code in XAML :

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding type}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="369" Margin="1,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="991" SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Width="60" Binding="{Binding id_type}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nom" Width="200" Binding="{Binding nom_type}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Couleur" Width="200" Binding="{Binding couleur_type}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

My code in ADOType :

```
public static List<TypeC> readAll()
    {
        try
        {

            List<TypeC> lesTypes = new List<TypeC>();
            MySqlDataReader reader; // Contiendra les données

            open();
            MySqlCommand requete = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM type");
            requete.Connection = conn;
            reader = requete.ExecuteReader(); // Exécution de la requête SQL
                                              // reader.Read(); // lecture du resultat
                                              // lesEntreprise = new Entreprise((String)reader["siret"]);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                lesTypes.Add(new TypeC((int)reader["id_type"], reader["nom_type"].ToString(), reader["couleur_type"].ToString()));
            }
            reader.Close();
            close();
            return lesTypes;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Affiche des erreurs
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            close();
            return null;
        }

    }
```

I use a readAll() and i would like display readAll() in my DataGrid.

Thanks for your help. I continue my search.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the same collection that you are populating using readAll() method in itemssource property of Datagrid.

Change your code as per below:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding lesTypes}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="369" Margin="1,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="991" SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Width="60" Binding="{Binding id_type}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nom" Width="200" Binding="{Binding nom_type}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Couleur" Width="200" Binding="{Binding couleur_type}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Also, change `List<TypeC>` to `ObservableCollection<TypeC>`. Observable Collection implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface and it will reflect any change that you made in collection on UI

Comment: I have changed but always empty... I recover values well in database but they do not want to display. I don't understand :/

Comment: can you please post relative parts of model and view model. It will help us to understand your issue better

Comment: I just missed a method "Refresh ()"

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to tell us what you are doing with the result of the `readAll()` method.

You should set the `type` property of your view model to it:

```
type = readAll();
```

...or the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` depending on where the method and the `type` property is defined and whether you are using the MVVM design pattern:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = readAll();
```

If you are setting the `type` property after the constructor of the view has returned, the view model class should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the `item` property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Also note that `id_type`, `nom_type` and `couleur_type` should be *public properties* of the `TypeC` class.

Comment: What should I put in the "ListTypeC.XAML.cs" to display the data in the datagrid? I didn't put anything in it.

Comment: dataGrid.ItemsSource = readAll(); Or you set the 'type' property (wherever that is defined) that the ItemsSource property is bound to.

Comment: I just missed a method "Refresh ()"

Comment: There is no need to call any Refresh() method after you have set the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid.